# mysql: condition and groupby some rows with zero values

Tags: mysql

Following is my query I want to display all items in a shop even if the count of items are zero

```
select count(itemn) as count, item from mytable group by item
This lists

count      item
 234        1
  45        2
  65        3
  23        4
```

but when I apply some conditions it's not showing all the items

```
select count(itemn) as count, item from mytable where price <230 group by item

count      item
 234        1
  23        4
```

But I want the results like

```
count     item
 234       1
   0       2
   0       3
  23       4
```

Comment: Can you show what values you have in the column price??

Comment: @nacho it's price with values like 320, 450,120,110

Comment: It seems that for item number 2 (and 3) you don't have any row with price <230, you should check that in your DB

Comment: Well the rows with values greater than 230 wont be included in the result

Comment: @RiggsFolly I want it to be displayed bro any ideas

Comment: @nacho then I want it to display 0 for rows 2 and 3

Comment: One of us, and its probably me, is not understanding what you are trying to achieve with this query

Comment: @RiggsFolly this is a client requirement I am just trying to implement it

Comment: Can you create an SQLFiddle with some test data so we can see a little more

Answer (score 0):

Just try to do it this way then:

```
select SUM(case 
    when price<230 then 1  
    else 0 
    end) as count, item 
from mytable 
group by item
```